# Displaying Hungarian Text - Arial works, but Futura CE doesn't

Tags: fonts, directx

I have programmed a 2D GUI in DirectX and it was working well until I had to use Hungarian letters. Thanks to the lovely people over at stack overflow I was able to get it rendering hungarian letters correctly, using the Arial font.

An example is the special character in FELNŐTTEKNEK.

My problem is I want to use Futura font. I bought Futura CE on the understanding that the CE means Central European, ie it contains the extra characters such as the Ő.

When I use this font the output is scrambled: edkm   ssdj    mdj

The font works in GIMP and Flash 8 :(
Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: The font [doesn't seem to have _all_ letters in the Latin-Extended-A class](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=321583), which I think you are referring to. Could you try to render a text that contains one letter from the extended range and show us what the _exact_ output is? The reason asking: auto-font-selection may be in use, which may have forced the _whole_ text to be displayed in a lesser font.

Comment: Other pointers are encoding, but then I'd say you should see the same problem in Arial.